# Do the width and height of a texture need to be even?

Tags: c++, opengl

It appears this way but I do not find this in the khronos documentation of glTexImage2D.
I am displaying an unsigned byte RGB test texture:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, width_, height_, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &textureV[0]);
```

This works fine if width_ = height_ = 60 (even):

[image]

However it fails if width_ = height_ = 59 (odd):

[image]

My version is:

```
OpenGL version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 443.18
```

Comment: Please add minimal reproducible code as your question doesn't contain much information.

Comment: If I remember right, the raw image data rows have to be aligned to multiples of 4. It happens that 60 * 3 = 180 -> a multiple of 4. But 59 * 3 = 177 -> no multiple of 4. - In the past, texture dimensions were restricted that they had to be a power of 2. This restriction does not exist anymore in the modern GPUs, AFAIK. Try to adjust your image data so that any row consumes a multiple of 4 bytes. Then even 59 x 59 should work, IMHO.

Comment: @Scheff: thank you. It seems you are right. width_ = height = 58 also failed. When I changed to GL_RGBA: 58, 59 and 60 all worked. I am therefore opting to use GL_RGBA instead. Too bad this does not seem to be documented.

Comment: It is documented - insofar as anything is documented in a spec; i.e., you need to know that the GL state machine has defaults, and that the defaults affect this issue... The default for `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` being: `(4)`. Calling: [`glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) is likely what you want.